# Transferring assets between accounts and pallet

Tags: substrate

I'm trying to create a pallet that users can deposit assets into and withdraw from.
I've written the following code, but I'm not sure it's the best way to about things due to frame_system::RawOrigin::Root.into() being accessible by every runtime.

I'm still fairly new to Substrate and not sure this is exactly how it works, would love some guidance on the best design choice.

Making use of assets pallet to deposit:

`<Assets::Module<T>>::transfer(origin, asset_id, RawOrigin::Root.into(), amount);`

To Withdraw:

`<Assets::Module<T>>::transfer(RawOrigin::Root.into(), asset_id, origin, amount);`

**Edit**

A similar idea written in Solidity:

```
contract DepositWithdrawSend {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public depositInfo;
    address public sendPallet;

    constructor(address _sendPallet) public {
        sendPallet = _sendPallet;
    }

    function deposit(address _token, uint256 _amount) public {
        IERC20(_token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        depositInfo[_token][msg.sender] = depositInfo[_token][msg.sender].add(_amount);
    }

    function withdraw(address _token, uint256 _amount) public {
        require(depositInfo[_token][msg.sender] >= _amount, "Over withdraw");
        require(IERC20(_token).balanceOf(address(this)) >= _amount, "Not enough");
        IERC20(_token).transfer(msg.sender, amount);
        depositInfo[_token][msg.sender] = depositInfo[_token][msg.sender].sub(_amount);
    }

    function send(address _token, uint256 _amount) public {
        require(IERC20(_token).balanceOf(address(this)) >= _amount, "Not enough");
        IERC20(_token).transfer(sendPallet, amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to substrate development :) -- for an example of how account balances are handled, the balances pallet is a great example: https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v3.0.0/pallet_balances/index.html and the source here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/balances

Comment: If you are using the assets pallet and want to interact with it in other pallets, checkout how to do that here: https://substrate.dev/recipes/pallet-coupling.html

Comment: "I'm trying to create a pallet that users can deposit assets into and withdraw from." - do you mean you want only to reserve balances like is done with the nicks pallet?   https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/nicks if so, checkout the tutorial for a look at how this is done: https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/add-a-pallet/

Comment: @NukeManDan Thanks for the replies! I'll definitely check out the recipes. What I'm trying to achieve is similar to something that can be done on Solidity. Where a contract can transfer a user's ERC20 into itself  (deposit), and transfer it back to the user (withdraw). The best way to achieve this is by using the ```assets``` pallet right? https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/assets/src/lib.rs

Comment: Happy to help! :) -- can you provide a simple example of such a contract in solidity I can see the logic in you want? Depending on what you want the _deposit_ to do once locked up, or what it should enable, assets may or may not be the right tool for the job (but likely is)

Comment: @NukeManDan I've added the Solidity example!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We follow a pretty simple pattern to give pallets their own "account" for transferring balances to or anything else.

First you create a unique `PalletId` representing your pallet:

```
use frame_support::PalletId;
const MyPalletId: PalletId = PalletId(*b"replace_");
```

Then from here, you can generate an `AccountId` from this `PalletId`:

```
use sp_runtime::traits::AccountIdConversion;

/// These actually do computation. If you need to keep using them,
/// then make sure you cache the value and only call them once.

pub fn account_id() -> T::AccountId {
    T::PalletId::get().into_account()
}

pub fn sub_account(seed: u16) -> T::AccountId {
    // only use two byte prefix to support 16 byte account id (used by test)
    // "modl" ++ "replace_" ++ "hi" is 14 bytes, and two bytes remaining for bounty index
    T::PalletId::get().into_sub_account(("hi", id))
}
```

This pattern is used in the [Treasury Pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/treasury/src/lib.rs) and others.